# Update table using the values of other table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to clean up my table:

```
rid(PK)     rval
----------- ----------
10          test
11          Rtest
12          dummy
13          test
14          Rtest
```

to remove the duplicate values from column `rval`, so I end up with:

```
rid(PK)     rval
----------- ----------
10          test
11          Rtest
12          dummy
```

But I have another table with a foreign key relationship which uses the values I want to delete:

```
ruid       rid(FK)
---------- ----------
1          10
2          10
3          12
4          13
5          13
6          14
7          14
```

so before I delete, I need to update that table to use the matching `rid` that I'm keeping, e.g. updating 14 to 11; so that table will end up as:

```
ruid       rid(FK)
---------- ----------
1          10
2          10
3          12
4          10
5          10
6          11
7          11
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an analytic aggregate to get the lowest `rid` for each `rval`:

```
min(rid) over (partition by rval)
```

and use that in a subquery that joins the two tables (which I've imaginatively called `t1` and `t2` as you haven't given their real names) so you can see the lowest suitable `rid` for each `ruid`:

```
select t2.ruid, t2.rid, x.min_rid
from (
  select rid, min(rid) over (partition by rval) as min_rid from t1
) x
join t2 on t2.rid = x.rid;

      RUID        RID    MIN_RID
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10         10
         2         10         10
         3         12         12
         4         13         10
         5         13         10
         6         14         11
         7         14         11
```

You can then use that in a merge statement:

```
merge into t2
using (
  select t2.ruid, t2.rid, x.min_rid
  from (
    select rid, min(rid) over (partition by rval) as min_rid from t1
  ) x
  join t2 on t2.rid = x.rid
) y
on (t2.ruid = y.ruid)
when matched then update set t2.rid = y.min_rid
where t2.rid != y.min_rid;

4 rows merged.

select * from t2;

      RUID        RID
---------- ----------
         1         10
         2         10
         3         12
         4         10
         5         10
         6         11
         7         11
```

Once you've done that you can remove the redundant PK values:

```
delete from t1
where exists (select * from t1 x where x.rval = t1.rval and x.rid < t1.rid);

2 rows deleted.

select * from t1;

       RID RVAL 
---------- -----
        10 test 
        11 Rtest
        12 dummy
```

---

Id `ruid` is not unique, and there is no other unique key you can include in the statement, then you can't really use a merge - you can't refer to `rid` in the `on` clause as that's the column you're updating.

You could do a correlated update instead:

```
update t2
set rid = (
  select min_rid
  from (
    select rid, min(rid) over (partition by rval) as min_rid from t1
  ) x
  where x.rid = t2.rid
);
```

That will update every row; if you have a lot of data and/or a small proportion need to change then you can add a filter to only update those:

```
update t2
set rid = (
  select min_rid
  from (
    select rid, min(rid) over (partition by rval) as min_rid from t1
  ) x
  where x.rid = t2.rid
)
where rid != (
  select min_rid
  from (
    select rid, min(rid) over (partition by rval) as min_rid from t1
  ) x
  where x.rid = t2.rid
);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked well!!!  And thank you for formatting my question.

Comment: Will duplicate RUIDs always have the same RID?

Comment: Duplicate RUID can have same and different both RID. for same RUID-RID I can use DISTINCT but if RID is not same, what to do in that case?

Comment: Can anyone suggest solution for duplicate RUID values?

Comment: @RGM - I've added a solution with a correlated update.

Comment: is there any other approach possible? I can use stored procedure also, it doesn't need to be single query.

Comment: You could do separate updates for each `rid` you want to remove, looping over the mappings in a PL/SQL block, but that will be slower and messier. What's wrong with these approaches?